# How to change the locals name in Localized Sites

Tags: localization, multi-site

I am developing multi-sites with the locals. Everything is fine. Is it possible to change the name of locals. I 'd like to give some other names to locals so that those can be more clear while managing the contents.

Please guide me for it.

Comment: anyone please ???

Answer (score 5):

You could add new pseudo localization files to Craft `craft/app/framework/i18n/data/` and rename (translate) the name of your "language" and other things in these files.

I'd use `en.php` as a starting point and save it as `en_custom.php`. Then add a new key/value pair `'en_custom' => 'My Custom Country'` to the `languages` array (line 205 ff.), which is responsible for the translation of the language names.

Comment: Probably worth noting that modifying anything in the `craft/app` folder is generally considered bad practice... Your changes can (and likely will) disappear during a future auto-update. That all being said, modifying the core might be your only option here. (reluctant +1)

Comment: Yes, this is no nice solution (as is to mis-use locales to get some sort of multi-site feature to begin with!!). But it works and auto-update probably doesn't do any harm to "unknown" localization files (Craft can't know if this is a real country, does it?).

Comment: Hmm, interesting theory. You might be right that "invented" localization files would be safe, but I personally would hesitate to take that risk. I generally think of auto-updates along the lines of git syncing... ie, "everything in its right place". But you're definitely right (unless P&T says otherwise) that there's no way to do this without tapping into the `craft/app` folder.

Comment: The only time it would be overwritten during an auto-update is if, instead of only sending a diff of patched files down, we decide to just swap out the whole app folder cart blanche. I think we've only done that once during a Yii update that touched so many files (thousands) it was less work just to swap out the whole folder.

Comment: @BradBell Would the eventual arrival of Craft 3 be an instance where you may decide to replace the entire `app` folder?

Comment: @BradBell it would be nice if you would exclude the i18n/data/ folder from such overwrites or allow users to define a custom (additional) path `CRAFT_LOCALES_PATH` to it in index.php. Not only for this use case but also for user installed non-fake locales that are not supported by default (see other Q/A here where you and Brandon suggested this).

Comment: @LindseyD There is about a 100% chance that Craft 3 is going to be a manual update only.

Comment: @carlcs - Maybe... it's a non-issue on Craft 3, though, so probably not worth the effort right now.

Comment: We are currently using this method on a site. If Craft 3 has a manually update, should copying the custom localization files to the proper folder before running the update allow for a smooth transition?