# Can I translate locale names?

Tags: localization

I've read all posts about localization and translation here and at Craft's documentation, but I still haven't found the answer.

What I want achieve here is having let's say UK instead of British English.

I found paragraph in documentation:

```
{{ "Welcome, {name}"|t({ name: user.friendlyName }) }}
```

**that says:** If your text contains dynamic variables, add tokens to the string where they should go, and pass an object to the t filter that contains their values

Could anything like that work by passing object to _locale.php in /translations folder and set other value? Tried, without effect.
Theoretically it could work, craft would pass the object of an active locale to our translation's file.

Any advice, so I don't waste time on something that can't be done.

Comment: Did you read this: ["How to change the locals name in Localized Sites"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/6631/125)?

Comment: First find. I will consider this as a second option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't be done, don't waste your time.

Only thing that could work is via a [static translations](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/static-translations) file, but the CP gets locale name data directly from that yii language file, so this is your only chance (see [dupe question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/6631/125)). Other things can be overwritten though, e.g `'Users' => 'Members'`.